# How to see table definition or download table script in apache ignite 2.8.1

Tags: ignite

I am using ignite 2.8.1 and trying to see table definition from ignite web console by using command like desc table_name. But it does not work. Did a detail study but did not find any commands or any approach which helps to download table creation script or see the table definition.

Please let me know if there is any approach by which we can download table script or see table definition in ignite (preferably from ignite web console)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if WebConsole can do the trick, this product is not supported anymore. But you can achieve it using any DB manager with JDBC support.

For example, here is the screenshot from DBeaber that has an embedded template for Apache Ignite JDBC drier. Check [this example](https://www.gridgain.com/resources/blog/get-started-apache-ignite-in-memory-database-imdb) on how to set it up (could be outdated though).

[image] .